# error module' object has no attribute 'LANCZOS

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, image-resizing

I  want to resize an image to 28*28 pixel `.jpeg`. And I use the module called `PIL` for resize this picture :
I created this class :

```
from PIL import Image

#import PIL
import numpy
from resizeimage import resizeimage

import scipy.misc

''' This class is to resize input image to MNIST size (28x28 px) '''


class Resize_img:
    def __init__(self, imageName):
        print 'Image -- ', imageName
        self.resized_image = ''
        # resize img to mnist size [28x28]
        #with open(imageName,'r+b') as f:
        #    with Image.open(f) as image:
    image = Image.open(imageName)        
        cover = resizeimage.resize_cover(image, [28, 28])
        self.resized_image = 'new ' + imageName
        cover.save(self.resized_image, image.format)
        # transform img to MNIST form
        # image to ndarray 
        PILimg = PIL.Image.open(self.resized_image)

        self.mnist_image_input = scipy.misc.fromimage(PILimg,
                                                      True)  # True => space gray! ----------------------------------------------------
        self.mnist_image_input = (numpy.multiply(self.mnist_image_input,
                                                 1.0 / 255.0) - 1.0) * -1.0  # inverse the image :D  ( white -> dark )


def main():  # To test this Class.
    imageTest = '2.jpeg'  # The name of the image to resize

    imageTest = Resize_img(imageTest)
    scipy.misc.imshow(imageTest.mnist_image_input)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


# sudo apt-get install libtiff4-dev libjpeg8-dev zlib1g-dev libfreetype6-dev liblcms2-dev libwebp-dev tcl8.5-dev tk8.5-dev python-tk
```

the error is :

```
Image --  2.jpeg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Resize_img.py", line 40, in <module>
    main()
  File "Resize_img.py", line 35, in main
    imageTest = Resize_img(imageTest)
  File "Resize_img.py", line 18, in __init__
    with Image.open(f) as image:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 528, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: __exit__
```

how resolved this problem  ?

Help on method resize in module PIL.Image:

```
resize(self, size, resample=0) unbound PIL.Image.Image method
    Returns a resized copy of this image.

    :param size: The requested size in pixels, as a 2-tuple:
       (width, height).
    :param filter: An optional resampling filter.  This can be
       one of :py:attr:`PIL.Image.NEAREST` (use nearest neighbour),
       :py:attr:`PIL.Image.BILINEAR` (linear interpolation in a 2x2
       environment), :py:attr:`PIL.Image.BICUBIC` (cubic spline
       interpolation in a 4x4 environment), or
       :py:attr:`PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS` (a high-quality downsampling filter).
       If omitted, or if the image has mode "1" or "P", it is
       set :py:attr:`PIL.Image.NEAREST`.
    :returns: An :py:class:`~PIL.Image.Image` object.
```

Comment: What is your question about ?

Comment: @Bodhi94 i"m editing the question

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, this is likely due to some missing dependency where LANCZOS was not installed on your system. You could try using BILINEAR, BICUBIC, NEAREST, or ANTIALIAS. To fix this, we need to dive into the resizeimage package. Assuming the package is located at: `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/resizeimage/`

We can edit the resizeimage file with:

`sudo nano /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/resizeimage/resizeimage.py`

Once inside, the file, we need to replace `LANCZOS` with `ANTIALIAS`. For example, in the `resize_cover` function:

`img = img.resize((new_size[0], new_size[1]), Image.LANCZOS)`

becomes:

`img = img.resize((new_size[0], new_size[1]), Image.ANTIALIAS)`

and so on for the rest of the functions in the file. This should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on your version of PIL. Try this in a python shell

```
>>> import PIL.Image                                                                                                                      
>>> help(PIL.Image.Image.resize)
```

Comment: Ok, then you can use NEAREST or BILINEAR or BICUBIC or ANTIALIAS but not LANCZOS

Comment: how to uses the NEAREST or BILINEAR or BICUBIC or ANTIALIAS ?

Comment: `img = img.resize((new_size[0], new_size[1]), Image.BILINEAR) `

Comment: The problem remains the same

Answer (score 0):

I actually do not see LANCZOS used in your code, but the fix would be to replace `Image.LANCZOS` with `Image.ANTIALIAS`. It is likely that you have a different version of Python installed than the one that uses LANCZOS. ANTIALIAS should perform equally when it comes to downsizing images and making them look crisp.

Answer (score 0):

Your dependencies are designed to work with a later version of Pillow. Just install latest [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/).